# Telegram Bot - get all chats list

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

My telegram bot database was accidentally deleted after I moved it to a new server.

Is there a way to obtain a list of all the numeric IDs of all users who have started the bot in the past? In reading Telegram's [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), I did not find any solution (although I've seen someone do it before and I am certain it can be accomplished); I found out from searches that it should probably be accomplished on the client side and using something like getDialogs.

https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getDialogs

Would anyone be able to assist me with that?

Comment: Removed the php mentions since this is pure Telegram based.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to obtain a list of all the numeric IDs of all users who have started the bot in the past?

No, Telegram can't offer a list like that.

If an update is removed from the `getUpdates()` call, it's gone for good.

---

> I found out from searches that it should probably be accomplished on the client side and using something like getDialogs.

The `getDialogs` you're looking at is part of the Telegram Core, used to create your own Client. This can't be used as a Bot.

---

So If you don't have a copy of your own, there won't be a way to tell all the users who have talked with your Bot, unless you ask them yourself ;)